# Unity: How can I get realtime image capturing at ~60fps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, real-time, capture

I am writing an application in Unity which will be required to capture an image from a camera every frame (at ~60fps), and send the resultant data to another service running locally.

The issue is, I am aware that capturing the rendered data from the camera can cause massive frame rate drops ([as explained in this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/real-time-image-capture-in-unity-458de1364a4c)) when using the `GetPixels()` method. The article explains that "GetPixels() blocks for ReadPixels() to complete" and "ReadPixels() blocks while flushing the GPU" which is why the GPU and CPU have to sync up, resulting in a lag.

I have produced a sample project with a script attached which simply outputs frames to a file as a PNG to replicate the functionality of the program I wish to create. I have done my best to implement what is described in the article, namely allowing the GPU to render a frame, then wait a few frames before calling `GetPixels()` so as not to cause the GPU and CPU to forcefully sync up. However, I really haven't made any progress with it. The project still plays at about 10-15fps.

How can I achieve a realtime capture of 60 frames per second in Unity?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets
{
    public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const float reportInterval = 0.5f;
        private int screenshotCount = 0;
        private const float maxElapsedSecond = 20;
        private string screenshotsDirectory = "UnityHeadlessRenderingScreenshots";
        public Camera camOV;
        public RenderTexture currentRT;
        private int frameCount = 0;
        private Texture2D resultantImage;

        public void Start()
        {
            camOV.forceIntoRenderTexture = true;
            if (Directory.Exists(screenshotsDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(screenshotsDirectory, true);
            }
            if (!Application.isEditor)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotsDirectory);
                camOV.targetTexture = currentRT;
            }
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        public void Update()
        {
            //Taking Screenshots
            frameCount += 1;
            if (frameCount == 1)
            {
                TakeScreenShot();
            }
            else if (frameCount == 3)
            {
                ReadPixelsOut("SS_"+screenshotCount+".png");
            }

            if (frameCount >= 3)
            {
                frameCount = 0;
            }
        }

        public void TakeScreenShot()
        {
            screenshotCount += 1;
            RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
            camOV.Render();
            resultantImage = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            resultantImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
            resultantImage.Apply();
        }

        private void ReadPixelsOut(string filename)
        {
            if (resultantImage != null)
            {
                resultantImage.GetPixels();
                RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

                byte[] bytes = resultantImage.EncodeToPNG();
                // save on disk
                var path = screenshotsDirectory + "/" + filename;
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

                Destroy(resultantImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The article implies that it is possible, but I haven't managed to get it to work.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First, I would change the update for a coroutine to use yield instead of the counter, just for readability. Second I would try to write on the disk on a separate thread so you can read/get while writing the previous frame. Finally, You seem to GetPixels and then encode to PNG. I am not quite sure why there is the GetPixels call considering you are not storing the result. It just acts as an expensive blank shot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if OP still need the answer. But in case someone in the future getting the same problem, Let me share what i found.

https://github.com/unity3d-jp/FrameCapturer

This is a plugin designed for rendering animation video in Unity editor. But it can also work in standalone. In my case, i take some part of it, and make my app stream Motion Jpeg. I did it with 30fps, never tried 60fps

Comment: This looks pretty good reo thetiklee, do you know any alternatives

Comment: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityRenderStreaming
This one seems using GPU for encoding, so it has better performance. And it's designed for WebRTC streaming. So yep. This would be my recent answer.

Comment: Oh wow great I've been looking all over couldn't find any thing like it, so you know if it encodes to a video file also and if it works at runtime?

Comment: i believe it's designed for streaming not recording

Comment: Ok so you know of anything that's designed for runtime, realtime hd recording, or is "frame capture" from your answer the only thing?